# How to omit xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" from web service output

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization

Can you help me how can I omit `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` declaration in each element in my output from asp.net web service (asmx)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DataItem>
    <Id xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">463d931f-5f14-447d-99cd-289cae2a5b6d</Id>
    <Created xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">2012-03-13T13:47:13.8626511+01:00</Created>
    ...
  </DataItem>
  ...
```

The web service is defined as follow:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]    
public class DataWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public DataCollection GetData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Data item is an EF entity:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="DataEntityModel", Name="DataItem")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class DataItem : EntityObject
{

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Guid Id
    {
       ...
    }
}


public class DataItemCollection : Collection<DataItem>
{

}
```

When I removed `[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]` from attributes, the result was the same.

Comment: What does your DataItem look like?

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove `[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]`. Instead, use your own namespace. Maybe something like `http://webservices.yourcompany.com/datawebservice`. You can also put explicit namespaces on your entities.

However, I would also suggest that you stop using ASMX services and instead use WCF.

Comment: I don't remove the namespace (it was just a try). The result is the same with or without the namespace. Probably when I remove the namespace, serializer put the default namespace instead. I'm using asmx because I need it (it is used in SSIS and with wcf it doesn't work correctly). The explicit namespaces on entities didn't help me.

Comment: You should try WCF using `basicHttpBinding`. Looks the same as ASMX on the network, but it's a modern technology, not a legacy technology like ASMX.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my first solution, but in this scenario (calling WCF service with basichttpbinding from SSIS Web Service Task) I have ended with the error describing here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/adodotnetentityframework/thread/81daac4c-231a-4460-8951-f168adee7d6e . I didn't  resolve this error, so I have moved to the asmx solution.